# How to page/swap out give region of user memory

Tags: linux-kernel, swap

I have to create test cases where user code accesses paged out (swapped out) memory in different scenarios.
I am looking for a Linux Kernel API that may do that for me. I suppose that:
- input arguments should be virtual address and the reference to the virtual space (MMU), 
- It will mark the page un-accessible by setting some bits in page table entry.
- get_user_pages API (that does the opposite)will know how to re-enable the access to the memory.

Comment: You can write your own proc entry or api to that. I don't think linux provides that.